# Problem with FileUtils.mkdir_p deleting folder contents

Tags: ruby, mkdir, fileutils

My "folder 3" contains "Folder 4A", but when I made a new folder within it, "Folder 4B", my "Folder 4A", and all it's contents got deleted.  What is wrong with my code, or is this normal for `FileUtils.mkdir_p`

`FileUtils.mkdir_p "/Users/Me/Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 3/Folder 4B"`

Comment: No, this is not normal. I guess something else is going on. Can you supply a complete step-by-step description on how to recreate he problem?

Comment: Is this on Windows?